# Rotating a clock hand in javascript

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am learning to make a clock using raphael js,

I am using this tutorial to get me started http://www.tuttoaster.com/creating-a-clock-animation-without-css3/

When this is diplayed the second hand doesnt move one second per second. I know one second is 6 degrees, it moves around 45 degrees though!

If someone could please explain what he has done wrong and how to make the hands rotate at appropriate angles that would be great. I am a beginner so plain english please :)

The code is as follows.

```
window.onload = function(){

var canvas = Raphael("pane",0,0,500,500);

canvas.circle(200,150,100).attr("stroke-width",2);
canvas.circle(200,150,3).attr("fill","#000");

var angleplus = 360,rad = Math.PI / 180,
cx = 200,cy =150 ,r = 90,
startangle = -90,angle=30,x,y, endangle;

 for(i=1;i<13;i++)
 {

     endangle = startangle + angle ;

     x = cx + r  * Math.cos(endangle * rad);
     y = cy + r * Math.sin(endangle * rad);

     canvas.text(x,y,i+"");

      startangle = endangle;
 }

var hand = canvas.path("M200 70L200 150").attr("stroke-width",1);
var minute_hand = canvas.path("M200 100L200 150").attr("stroke-width",2);
var hour_hand = canvas.path("M200 110L200 150").attr("stroke-width",3);

var time = new Date();

angle = time.getSeconds() * 6;

minute_hand.rotate(6 * time.getMinutes(),200,150);

var hr = time.getHours();
if(hr>12)
hr = hr -11;

hour_hand.rotate(30 * hr,200,150);

var minute_angle= 6 + time.getMinutes()*6,hour_angle=0.5+   
      time.getMinutes()*30;
setInterval(function(){
                 angle = angle + 6;
                 if(angle>=360)
                 {
                     angle=0;

                minute_hand.rotate(minute_angle,200,150);
                 minute_angle = minute_angle + 6;

                  hour_hand.rotate(hour_angle,200,150);
                      hour_angle = hour_angle + 0.5;
                 }
                  if(minute_angle>=360)
                  {
                      minute_angle=0;

                  }

                 hand.rotate(angle,200,150);

                 },1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hand.rotate(6,200,150);
```

Bernard, you don't need to rotate by the variable *angle* since you're simply rotating by 6 degrees every second regardless of how many seconds have elapsed.

http://jsbin.com/domoqojipe/1/

Comment: Thanks! That is actually what I meant, apologies. So, is this code not great then? Should I change just the part you have written above? Sorry I begun this course last week, I am just getting the hang of this..

Comment: Oh wow thanks!! That works great. Thanks so much. The person who wrote this code rotated by the variable angle!! Should the others be changed too or is it just that one? Thanks! Now i just need to work out how to make it display current time. I have asked a new question on this as it was a little late to add to this one. Any help much appreciated I will accept your answer :)

Comment: I have never used Raphael before so I was just seeing if I could figure this particular problem out. Glad I could help, but I'm not sure I'm your best resource overall. You should probably ask a new question. Best of luck!

Comment: haha no worries! I asked a new question and someone made a comment saying I shouldnt have done that so thought i would ask. :) Thats great though, sure I will work the rest out. I am guessing I am to leave the rest of the code alone?  i.e. hour_hand.rotate(hour_angle,200,150) and minute_hand.rotate(hour_angle,200,150)?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to speed up the clock speed by twenty?

It's a long shot, but try changing the `1000` at the bottom to `50`. Because 1000 divided by 20 equals 50.

Try that and see if it works...

Comment: That is the speed that the interval run at in milliseconds. 1000 ms = 1 s. I don't know why, but it was bugged out or something.

Comment: I still do not have a standard ticking clock. Must be error in code. Further help appreciated thanks